# Spring Boot returns Whitelabel Error Page instead of JSON

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I need RESTful service to return JSON every time regardless if there is error or not. With normal cases everything goes ok, but when exceptions come I see **Whitelabel Error Page**.

I tried to resolve this in two ways.

Through @ExceptionHandler inside @Controller class inside the class annotated with @RestController:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ErrorResponse handleException(Exception e) {
    return new ErrorResponse(5, "Error message");

}
```

And through special class with @ControllerAdvice annotation:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController {

    @ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public ErrorResponse handleSecurityException(MyCustomException e) {
        return new ErrorResponse(5, "Error message");
    }

}
```

In both cases through breakpoints I see that those methods was called, but I still receive **Whitelabel Error Page**.

So what am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of exception being thrown?  Maybe it's not a MyCustomException?

Comment: No, it's exactly MyCustomException. As I already wrote handler methods are called when it's thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I forgot to implement getters and setters for ErrorResponse class.